# Please give me some suggestions

Tags: phrase-requests

I am a new student to learn English. But I can't make
sentence good enough. So suggest me please, how can I .

Comment: What do you mean by "good enough"? The words don't flow well? Sentences not long enough?

Answer (score 1):

## Read

The more you read, the more you learn. At one point, you will be able to take what you read and form them into your own sentences. Start out with some books that are easier. Once you get the hang of it, you can browse around libraries for harder books with more challenging vocabulary. Observe their sentence structures, and their vocabulary.

## Study

I'm sure there are many websites out there that you can find with a simple search. Find a good website where you can improve your vocabulary, or one that gives suggestions. Grammarly is one, except it costs money and I'm not sure if you'd want to spend money on it.

## Practice

Practice writing blogs posts or stories. They don't have to be a work of art. Write well so that you can practice the flow and the rhythm of your sentences.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for help...But I can't memorise lot of vocabulary .Because my mother tongue isn't English. So what to do?